# Converting a .fig file to a .obj file in MATLAB

Tags: file, matlab

I have a 3D plot in MATLAB, a .fig file, that I need to export as a .obj file so that I can manipulate it in a graphic design program.  The program needs to have the file as x y z coordinates so a .dxf file would also work.  Has anyone ever had to do something like this?  I admit I'm not that experienced using MATLAB but would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Hey,

You seem to have received the response you requested over at the main discussion @ MATLAB Central [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/301722), so please don't repeat post.

Rgds

Comment: Ah, but one of those responses was a joke and the other wasn't that useful.  I was hoping others might have suggestions.

Comment: What information do you actually need? Would faces and vertices suffice?

Answer (score 2):

There is a "saveobjmesh" function available that might do what you need:

http://www.nada.kth.se/~asa/Ray/matlabobj.html

The web page has got examples of how to use it.